# Ubuntu reinstalled, but DNS problem still persists

Tags: 20.04, dns

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I encountered "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED", "DNS_probe_finished_bad_config", "DNS PROBE FINISHED NXDOMAIN" errors and tried lots and lots of fixes from stackexchange. None of that worked.

I thought I messed up everything and tried reinstalling Ubuntu (3 times) but the DNS is still messed up.

Its so weird and I've never had any problem prior to this, and my dual boot windows works just fine. This is like a dead end for my Ubuntu. What should I do now?

Comment: Maybe setting your dns to a different ip works? Like 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1?

Comment: @Irsu85 yes, tried that...

Comment: The try changing it to Google's: 8.8.8.8

Comment: If you use Wifi, try switching to an ethernet connection

Comment: The question is currently so vague that it seems unanswerable. What leads you to believe that it's an Ubuntu-related issue instead of a networking problem (bad cable, router setting, etc)? Your question claims to have "tried lots," but you have not provided ANY troubleshooting information from those efforts.

Comment: @user535733 Its vague coz that's all I know. I believe its a Linux problem coz I can access internet from the same Wi-Fi in the same computer through Windows. And the troubleshooting methods I used doesn't matter coz I uninstalled my ubuntu, installed again, then uninstalled again, then installed other distros (lubuntu, Debian, deepin, zorin). I believe its either some configuration file that wont be removed with uninstall or a BIOS setting.

Comment: That information should be in your question above (you can [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1336897/edit)), please. @Irsu85 offered an excellent troubleshooting step: change the networking method. That will isolate several of the most common causes of networking problems.

Comment: @Akshaykn Hello! You could try to update your question with the information you had previously provided in the last comment. I would also recommend that you give detailed information of the hardware where you are trying to install Ubuntu. It is possible that the kernel is not interacting well with the device. Try to find out the network card information in particular. If a laptop, giving the computer model should help others point things out.